# Rails has_one build_association deletes record before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

So this has been asked previously, but with no satisfying answers.

Consider two models, `User`, and `Subscription` associated as such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
end
```

Inside of SubscriptionsController, I have a new action that looks like this

```
def new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @subscription = user.build_subscription
end
```

Given that a subscription already exists for a user record, I'm faced with the following problem:

`user.build_subscription` is ***destructive***, meaning that simply ***visiting*** the `new` action actually destroys the association, thereby losing the current subscription record.

Now, I could simply check for the subscription's existence and redirect like this:

```
def new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if user.subscription.present?
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        @subscription = user.build_subscription
    end
end
```

But that doesn't seem all that elegant.

**Here's my question**

Shouldn't just building a ***tentative*** record for an association ***not be destructive***?
Doesn't that violate RESTful routing, since `new` is accessed with a GET request, which ***should not*** modify the record?

Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong. Should I be building the record differently? Maybe via `Subscription.new(user_id: user.id)`? Doesn't seem to make much sense.

Would much appreciate an explanation as to why this is implemented this way and how you'd go about dealing with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do

---

**Thoughts**

From what you've posted, it seems the `RESTful` structure is still valid for you. You're calling the `new` action on the `subscriptions` controller, which, by definition, means you're making a new subscription (not loading a current subscription)?

You have to remember that Rails is basically just a group of Ruby classes, with instance methods. This means that you don't need to keep entirely to the `RESTful` structure if it doesn't suit

I think your issue is how you're handling the request / action:

```
def new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @subscription = user.build_subscription
end
```

`@subscription` is building a new `ActiveRecord` object, but doesn't need to be that way. You presumably want to change the subscription (if they have one), or create an association if they don't

---

**Logic**

Perhaps you could include some logic in an instance method:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    def build
       if subscription
           subscription
       else
           build_subscription
       end
    end

end

#app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb
def new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @subscription = user.build
end
```

This will give you a populated ActiveRecord, either with data from the subscription, or the new `ActiveRecord` object.

---

**View**

In the view, you can then use a select box like this:

```
#app/views/subscriptions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
    <%= "User #{params[:user_id]}'s subscription: %>
    <%= f.collection_select :subscription_id, Subscription.all,:id , :name %>
<% end %>
```

They are my thoughts, but I think you want to do something else with your code. If you give me some comments on this answer, we can fix it accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

I also always thought, that a `user.build_foobar` would only be written to the db, if afterwards a `user.save` is called. One question: After calling `user.build_subscription`, is the old subscription still in the database?

What is the output `user.persisted?` and `user.subscription.persisted?`, after calling `user.build_subscription`?

Your method to check if a subscription is present, is IMHO absolutely ok and valid.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today and agree that deleting something from the db when you call build is a very unexpected outcome (caused us to have bad data).  As you suggested, you can work around if very easily by simply doing Subscription.new(user: user).  I personally don't think that is much less readable then user.build_subscription.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018 Richard Peck's solution worked for me:

```
 #app/models/user.rb
 Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    def build_a_subscription
       if subscription
           subscription
       else
           build_subscription
       end
    end
  end
```

My issue was that a user controller didn't have a new method, because users came from an api or from a seed file. 
So mine looked like:

```
#app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.build_a_subscription
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

And I was finally able to have the correct singular version of subscriptions in my fields_for, so `:subscription` verses `:subscriptions`

```
#app/views
<%= f.fields_for :subscription do |sub| %>
  <%= render 'subscription', f: sub %>
<% end %>
```

Before I could only get the fields_for to show in the view if I made subscriptions plural. And then it wouldn't save. 
But now, everything works.